# How to indent spreadsheet cells in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

It's a fundamental feature that I need in my financial work but I can't seem to get this working in Google Sheets, or it doesn't support it.

I've also looked into Zoho Sheet, but they also don't support this.

Can it be done in Google Sheets, or should I look to another web app?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of an app that shows indention?

Comment: Gnumeric does this: [Gnumeric screenshot](https://plus.google.com/photos/101323841079559711175/albums/5745888187008149697?authkey=CJ-Yztro_OiRdQ)

Answer (score 3):

You can type either <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> to insert non-breaking spaces to create indentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can indent values in cells using [EditGrid](http://www.editgrid.com/site/learn/feature/spreadsheet) which free.

It provides with a whole range of Excel like functionality.

> Cut-and-paste, sorting, charts,
>   auto-fill, cell border, number
>   formatting, cell formatting, import,
>   export, print, find, undo, redo,
>   freeze pane, text overflow, auto-fit
>   row/column size, word warp, cell
>   comments, 500+ functions ... You name
>   it, EditGrid has it.
>
> EditGrid can import/export your
>   spreadsheets from/to many popular
>   spreadsheet file formats, including
>   Microsoft Excel (.xls), OpenDocument
>   (.ods), OpenOffice.org (.sxc), CSV
>   (.csv), and many others.

You can try out an online demo of EditGrid [here](http://www.editgrid.com/site/try/demo)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a formula to create an indentation.

### Formula

```
=CONCAT(REPT(CHAR(160),3),"test")
```

### Explained

The white space (`CHAR(160)`) is repeated 3 times and combined with the text `test` via the `CONCAT` formula.

### Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this custom function in a Google script attached to the spreadsheet:

```
function indent(_txt, _spaces) {
  var txt = (!_txt) ? "Test text" : _txt;
  var spaces = (!_spaces) ? 2 : _spaces;
  var space = " ";
  var f = '';
  for (var i=0; i<spaces; i++) {
    f += space;
  }
  f += txt;
  return f;
}
```

IMPORTANT:  The space that you enter in the var space = " " line should be a SHIFT-ALT/OPTION-SPACE from Alex and Hannah above.

Use the function in the spreadsheet like this:  =indent("Indent me", 2)

Answer (score -2):

On Google Doc Spreadsheets, you can do this by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt (Option)</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: Couldn't get this to work. Should one be in "edit the cell" mode or "move around the screen" mode?

Comment: Could not get this to work either.

Comment: Could not get this to work either.